# chrome jsessionid added to each url and it changes for every request

Tags: google-chrome, jsessionid

I don't know what has been changed on this machine. Only Chrome has this issue. The jsessionid is added to every URL and it changes all the time so log on will not work. I tried IE and Firebox and they both work fine. Chrome used to work fine on this machine as well, i.e. without the jsessionid. I don't recall I did any changes Chrome specific. I also tried from another machine with Chrome and it worked fine too. So it is just one machine that Chrome creates jesssionid all the time. I tried a few solutions from the web, but nothing worked for me.  This is really odd. What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to add that the same web app deployed on another machine worked too even with Chrome from this machine. So it is just the combination of Chrome and this deployment on this machine that has this problem. I did attempt to add SSL to the Tomcat instance on this machine. But then I restored the Connector settings to plain http so I don't think this is SSL related.

Comment: Check if you have cookies enabled on Chrome. jsessionid can be added when cookies are disabled.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't find the exact Chrome setting that did this but once I reset all its settings, everything is working fine.

Comment: Glad that it's fixed. Accept my answer (below) if you wish as this might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsessionid is added if cookies are disabled on the browser (either for all sites or for your particular sites). Some sites in this case will resort back to using session id as a query string parameter which is what you are seeing.

Enabling cookies will fix this issue.